# How do I create indexing for firestore mutliple orderBy queries?

Tags: indexing, google-cloud-firestore

My firestore model is like

> {
>            foods : [
>                'butter, cheese' : {
>                     "Energy - kcal" : 122,
>                     "Carbohydrate - g" : 33,
>                     "Fat - g" : 23
>                },
>                .
>                .
>            ]
>       }

```
let query = db.collection("foods");
let list = ["Energy - kcal","Carbohydrate - g"];
for(let i=0;i<list.length;i+=1) {
    let each = list[i];
    switch (each) {
        case "Energy - kcal":
            query = query.orderBy("Energy - kcal","desc");
            break;
        case "Carbohydrate - g":
            query = query.orderBy("Carbohydrate - g","desc");
            break;
        case "Cholesterol - g":
            query = query.orderBy("Cholesterol - g","desc");
            break;
        case "Fat - g":
            query = query.orderBy("Fat - g","desc");
            break;
        case "Protein - g":
            query = query.orderBy("Protein - g","desc");
            break;
        case "Fatty acids - g":
            query = query.orderBy("Fatty acids - g","desc");
            break;
        case "Sodium - mmg":
            query = query.orderBy("Sodium - mmg","desc");
            break;
        case "Potassium - mmg":
            query = query.orderBy("Potassium - mmg","desc");
            break;
        case "sugar":
            query = query.orderBy("sugar","desc");
            break;
        case "fiber":
            query = query.orderBy("fiber","desc");
            break;
        case "calcium":
            query = query.orderBy("calcium","desc");
            break;
        case "iron":
            query = query.orderBy("iron","desc");
            break;
        case "vitamin_a":
            query = query.orderBy("vitamin_a","desc");
            break;
        case "vitamin_c":
            query = query.orderBy("vitamin_c","desc");
            break;
    }
}
```

I have tried indexing all attributes with descending order but still getting 
[image]

> Error: 9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index

**What should proper way to identify which fields are used in indexing and how do I take advantage of Cloud Firestore's ability to merge indexes?**

Thanks,

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview%23taking_advantage_of_index_merging&ved=2ahUKEwjG8a3VtcfgAhXVeisKHf9KDrEQygQwAHoECAEQAg&usg=AOvVaw3i_d9Ox0kVaACikHlubBx_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of index merging only when you are using multiple (chained) `where()` function calls in your query. Since your query will always have a **single** `where()` call based on a single value from within that `list` along with an `orderBy()` call, you cannot merge anything. So you need to create an index for each property separately.

**Edit:**

According to your comment, if you need to query your data according to 14 properties separately and order them it the same time, this is the solution. It's not a good one but this what you have. In your case, I recommend deploy indexes with the [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing#use_the_firebase_cli).

Comment: But then there are total 14 types of attributes then total 2^14 indexes will be there which is not good solution

Comment: I know is not what you expected byt this is how it works. Please also see my updated answer.